# trouble modeling cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, cql

I want to use cassandra to save logs and read them later

Here is what I've done so far :

```
CREATE TABLE logs
(
    id uuid,
    type int,
    start_date timestamp,
    end_date timestamp,
    ip text,
    log_event text,
    user_id text,
    user_agent text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, type, start_date, user_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (type ASC, start_date DESC, profil_token ASC);
```

What I need is always this kind of query :

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE type = 1 AND user_id = 'test' AND start_date = '2017-03-08';
```

I need to query without id, but I can't because id is my real primary key

I don't see how to achieve this kind of query without ALLOW FILTERING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on if you need the query to be fast. If you don't and can live with scanning over all rows, then `ALLOW FILTERING` is your fix.

If you need the query to be fast, you can either restructure the table so you're querying on a prefix or you can create a new table, denormalizing your data for faster queries.

I don't know enough about your use case, but making `user_id` part of the clustering key might work for you:

```
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, start_date, type, id)
```

But this means you can't look up by `id` without knowing the `user_id` (and other fields). You could add a secondary index for that, though.

Answer (score 2):

> What I need is always this kind of query :
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM logs WHERE type = 1 AND user_id = 'test' AND start_date = '2017-03-08';
> ```

If *always* really means **always** this table model is a bit incorrect. Your model should **always** be *query-driven*, so I'd model this as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE logs
(
    id uuid,
    type int,
    start_date timestamp,
    end_date timestamp,
    event_time timestamp,
    ip text,
    log_event text,
    user_id text,
    user_agent text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((type, user_id, start_date), event_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_time ASC);
```

When querying this table you clearly need to specify `type`, `user_id`, `start_date`, and *optionally* the new field `event_time` to filter the results.

If you modeled your original table to satisfy another query, then simply add a new table like the previous one and stay away from `ALLOW FILTERING`.

It will work flawlessy.